# Can I disable basic authentication for a specified path?

Tags: traefik

I use this Traefik (v1.7) file code to generate a basic auth:

```
[frontends]

  [frontends.whoami]
    backend = "whoami"

    [frontends.whoami.routes]
      [frontends.whoami.routes.route0]
        rule = "Host:whoami.local"

    [frontends.whoami.auth]
      [frontends.whoami.auth.basic]
        usersFile = ".htpasswd"
```

Is it possible to deactivate the basic auth for the following path with all his sub paths?
`http://whoami.local/api`
`http://whoami.local/api/xxx`

Comment: I would be interested in this too

Comment: It is not possible with v1 of Traefik. You need to define a new route/rule with a more specific path and do not define basic auth for this. If this rule matches, then it will be load without the basic auth.